# getting info about mac OS X application programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, objective-c++

I'm looking for cocoa framework that acquires the following information for each application : vendor name, version and full application name.

Alternatively, I could use a file that contain this information ... I've tried to search it in /Application/(name).app/... but I couldn't find it in specific location that is the same for all applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in the `info.plist` under `CFBundleName`

If you go into `<application>/contents/info.plist` you'll find it there

from the [ documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-109585):

> CFBundleName (String - iOS, OS X) identifies the short name of the
>   bundle. This name should be less than 16 characters long and be
>   suitable for displaying in the menu bar and the app’s Info window. You
>   can include this key in the InfoPlist.strings file of an appropriate
>   .lproj subdirectory to provide localized values for it. If you
>   localize this key, you should also include the key
>   CFBundleDisplayName.

here's an example code for acquiring version from Info.plist of a selected application:

```
string GetAppVersion(string app)
{
    NSString *vlcFilePath = [NSString stringWithCString:app.c_str()];
    NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:vlcFilePath] infoDictionary];
    NSString* version = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
}
...
...
GetAppVersion("/Applications/Notes.app").c_str());
```